# Using COM interfaces C# to access from c++ produces error

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I have a c++ project that will call a C# function and afterwards, the c# will call a c++ function (both with return values). Im stuck at the COM interface that someone here on stackoverflow gave to me (i dont have much experience on c++ or c#, only java), but for some reason it gives me an error when i try to compile the C++ CODE, fatal error C1196: 'FaceTrackingBasics-WPF' : identifier found in type library c:\FaceTrackingBasics-WPF/bin/x86/Debug/FaceTrackingBasics-WPF.tlb' is not a valid C++ identifier.

Can u spot some error? maybe i shouldn't have two classes in one file? btw, the c# code is associated with a window, i dont know if it causes problems or not.
Thanks

C# Code

```
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                ------------------------------------
    // <copyright file="FaceTrackingViewer.xaml.cs" company="Microsoft">
    //     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    // </copyright>
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------        ------------------------------------

    namespace FaceTrackingBasics
    {
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking;

using System.Globalization;

/////
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


using Point = System.Windows.Point;

/// <summary>
/// Class that uses the Face Tracking SDK to display a face mask for
/// tracked skeletons
/// </summary>
public partial class FaceTrackingViewer : UserControl, IDisposable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KinectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Kinect", 
        typeof(KinectSensor), 
        typeof(FaceTrackingViewer), 
        new PropertyMetadata(
            null, (o, args) => ((FaceTrackingViewer)o).OnSensorChanged((KinectSensor)args.OldValue, (KinectSensor)args.NewValue)));

    private const uint MaxMissedFrames = 100;



    private Boolean drawFlat = false;

    public FaceTrackingViewer()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    ~FaceTrackingViewer()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public KinectSensor Kinect
    {
        get
        {
            return (KinectSensor)this.GetValue(KinectProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(KinectProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }


    //i deleted the rest of the code, i dont think its relevant
    }
}

//***********************//

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("2EF06BCB-A25B-41AD-B233-33A956DBEB69")]
public struct Ponto
{
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Ponto(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("EB9258F5-DCFB-4F91-8342-5A05EB17557D")]
public interface IManagedClass
{
    Ponto[] Foo();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("11B23AD7-F79E-45D7-BC87-89F0DBC8B83F")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ManagedClass : IManagedClass
{
    private List<Ponto> points;

    public ManagedClass()
    {
        points = new List<Ponto>();
        points.Add(new Ponto(1.0, 1.0));
        points.Add(new Ponto(2.0, 2.0));
        points.Add(new Ponto(3.0, 3.0));
    }

    public Ponto[] Foo()
    {
        return points.ToArray();
    }
}
```

c++ Code

```
   #include "stdafx.h"

   #import        "C:/Users/Pedro/Dropbox/0000000TESE/000_visual_studio/0FaceTMS/FaceTrackingBasics-              WPF/bin/x86/Debug/FaceTrackingBasics-WPF.tlb"
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace FaceTrackingBasics;
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
::CoInitialize(NULL);

{
    IManagedClassPtr pManagedClass(__uuidof(ManagedClass));

    SAFEARRAY* psa = pManagedClass->Foo();
    Ponto* pPoints = (Ponto*)psa->pvData;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        cout << pPoints[i].x << " " << pPoints[i].y << endl;
}

::CoUninitialize();
 }
```

Comment: In the `#import` path there is 14 spaces, after `FaceTrackingBasics-`, are those spaces supposed to be there, and are they in your original code?

Comment: Have you modify you're assambly like [ComVisible(true)] ?

Comment: scott, its a copy paste bug, in my code its all together, no spaces.
thanatos, i dont know what you mean, but i have that 'directive' in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'FaceTrackingBasics-WPF' : ... is not a valid C++ identifier
```

It is not, a C++ identifier cannot contain a dash, "-".  Just like C# btw.  This name came from your project name.  Which set the type library name.  Which set the name of the namespace that the #import directive created.

Several possible workarounds beyond simply renaming your project.  You can [apply attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/298h7faa%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to the #import directive.  Like "auto-rename", "no-namespace" and "rename-namespace":

```
   #import "FaceTrackingBasics-WPF.tlb" rename_namespace("managed")
   using namespace managed;
```

Comment: thanks! i did what u said, it now can build the solution but visual studio still gives me red's on "using namespace managed" and on all of my main class of the c++ code. any thoughts?

Comment: i was missing #include <Windows.h> . it solved, thanks for all the help!